# Vim: How can I remap a key, but only when I combined it with a number?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I want to center the view after I move up/down multiple lines (e.g. `7j`), but not when I only move once (e.g. `j` but I don't care about `1j`). Here's what I have:

```
:noremap j jzz
```

How can I make this work only when I combine the key with a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
function! s:MoveAndCenter(motion)
    return a:motion . (v:count > 1 ? 'zz' : '')
endfunction

noremap <silent> <expr> j <sid>MoveAndCenter('j')
noremap <silent> <expr> k <sid>MoveAndCenter('k')
```

This tells Vim to run an expression every time <kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd> are pressed, and use the returned string from that expression as the the normal mode command to run.  The reason we don't add the count to the result is that Vim automatically adds it (in fact, that behavior cannot be prevented).

See:

```
:help :map-expr
:help v:count
```

Comment: Sweet, thank you. I improved the function with `line(...)` to only center when I jump to a line that is not visible in the current window.